# Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed

Tags: hibernate

I am only trying to saveOrUpdate in Hibernate, I see that the sql is being generated but the insert is not running. I am seeing all exceptions. The only thing is in the entity that I am trying to save has a composite id. Not that this would cause this but just would like to state that.

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    user_restr
    (access, dname, user_id, sat) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?)


65033 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: -79716, SQLState: IX000
65034 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - System or internal error java.io.IOException
65071 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
65134 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
65151 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] WARN  org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory - Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:296) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory.getErrorCodes(SQLErrorCodesFactory.java:214) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.setDataSource(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:141) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.<init>(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:104) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.getDefaultJdbcExceptionTranslator(HibernateTransactionManager.java:817) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.getMetaData(IfxSqliConnect.java:2642) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [na:1.7.0]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.invoke(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:74) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at $Proxy46.getMetaData(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:285) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
65154 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - Could not toggle autocommit
java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setAutoCommit(IfxSqliConnect.java:2142) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:224) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:216) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [na:1.7.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0]
65156 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - JDBC rollback failed
java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.rollback(IfxSqliConnect.java:2075) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:676) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:892) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:782) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [na:1.7.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0]
65161 [http-bio-8080-exec-11] ERROR org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate flushing: Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into user_restrict_acc (access_level, datatype_name, user_id, satellite) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [IX000]; error code [-79716]; System or internal error java.io.IOException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80) [spring-jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:805) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:791) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120) [spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622) [spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [na:1.7.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [na:1.7.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) [servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) [catalina.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: System or internal error java.io.IOException
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:488) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.a(IfxSqli.java:9217) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2549) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.executeRelease(IfxSqli.java:2157) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxStatement.close(IfxStatement.java:518) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closePreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:563) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.closeStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:291) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:271) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133) [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656) [spring-orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.informix.asf.IfxDataInputStream.readFully(IfxDataInputStream.java:148) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.asf.IfxDataInputStream.readSmallInt(IfxDataInputStream.java:453) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqli.receiveMessage(IfxSqli.java:2514) [ifxjdbc-3.70.JC1.jar:na]
    ... 57 common frames omitted
Sep 01, 2012 10:07:07 PM com.vaadin.Application terminalError
SEVERE: Terminal error:
Cause: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:679)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:892)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:782)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:200)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:676)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection not established
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:413)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.rollback(IfxSqliConnect.java:2075)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:192)
    ... 46 more
```